# memory leak in CreateList function (linked list)

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list, valgrind

I tried checking for memory leak using valgrind with below options:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full -v ./linkedlist2
```

Valgrind says there is a memory leak in `createList()` function, but I am not able to find the reason for it. Could you please help me to understand what is the reason for the memory leak?

Relevant code:

```
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* createList(int num)
{
    struct node* temp = NULL;
    struct node* head = NULL;
    struct node* curr = NULL;

    int i = 0;
    if(num <= 0)
    {
        printf("Invalid size for createList\n");
        return;
    }

    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //allocate memory
        temp->data = i+1;
        temp->next = NULL;

        if(i == 0)
        {
            head = temp;
            curr = temp;
        }else   {
            curr->next = temp;
            curr = temp;
        }
    }
    curr = temp = NULL;
    //curr->next = temp->next = NULL;
    free(curr);free(temp);
    return head;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you think `curr->next = temp;
                                    curr = temp;` will do?

Comment: try using `curr->next = temp;
                                    curr = curr->next` ; Also I have compiled it on my system, it's working fine. Which OS are you using?

Comment: You are setting temp to NULL then calling free().  Reverse the order.  There is that, and calling malloc inside a loop, and then freeing outside, so ... there are other control flow problems to work out at as well.

Comment: This is just the createList function right? Do you have a freelist also? Are you calling it in main?

Comment: Use debug symbol to have the line number into your valgrind output. Use  `gcc -g`

Comment: @rkm_Hodor_king: I too compiled the program on my system and it works fine. I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @Jay: Yes, there is a seperate function to free the list. My objective was to just create a list, traverse the list and print the data and in the end free the allocated memory. I thought pasting the entire code could be problematic as it is pretty long. Thanks all :)

Comment: @BrianTiffin: Thanks Brian :) valgrind gives same error without those two free() statements. I added it to check if not freeing the curr and temp pointers was the real issue. I have a seperate function to free elements of linked list. So i am really not sure why this issue is occuring.

Answer (score 1):

This line causes the problem

```
curr = temp = NULL;
//curr->next = temp->next = NULL;
free(curr);free(temp);
```

Well here you are assigning `NULL` to struct node pointer `curr` and `temp`, henceforth the memory pointed by it goes garbage. you first free the memory using `free()` and the assign it to `NULL`

**Replace your above code with this**

```
free(curr);
free(temp);
curr = temp = NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) However, i found the error to be in the freeList() function that i had written. Since valgrind indicated source of memory leak as createList(), i didnt bother to check freeList() diligently. I fixed it and the memory leak error is gone. Thanks all for the suggestions and patience :)

Comment: @Tomislav Kostic;@All: I had placed a return statement within while loop of freeList() function which caused to free only a single node of the list. I removed the return statement which fixed the issue.

Comment: @UmashankarVarma But you did not put code of `freeList()` function, so It's hard to get that :p

Comment: Yes sir, my bad. Being a newbie, i did not think the error could be because of incorrect implementation of freeList(). Also, since this was going to be my first question on StackOverflow, i didnt want to make it longer by adding what i thought at the time to be "Unnecessary" code. Glad that i was proved wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should know is that for every allocation of memory(malloc()) you need to free that memory(free()),and that is exactly what valgrind returned as answer[image]

this lines of code would fix that

```
while(head!=NULL){
    temp=head;
    head=head->next;
    free(temp);
   }
```

But function createList() is supposed to create list not to delete it, so except for mental gymnastic I do not see purpose of creating list than immediately deleting. I recommend that you make new function removeList() that free memory which you call at the end of main function.

Comment: Thanks Tomislav :) I have a freeList() function which de-allocates memory which was previously allocated by malloc. Thats why this memory leak issue in createList() is a source of mystery to me.